# How to hide plugins style sheets in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i want to hide few **plugins style sheets** to reduce load on our Index page and categories pages. Actually we want to display plugin style sheet only on **Post** not on other pages.

we have used following code in plugin, but it doesn't work. please help how to use it.

```
if( is_single() || is_singular('post') ) wp_enqueue_style('savrix-style.css');
```

Comment: Did you create the plugin yourself, or are you modifying a third-party plugin? `is_singular('post')` should work just fine for your need - `is_single()` is not needed (and will result in the stylesheet being included on all other post types except pages and attachments). I assume that the `wp_enqueue_style` call itself is working(?) - ie. you have a `wp_register_style` call somewhere else, that defines `savrix-style.css` as the *handle* of the script, not the *filename* (as this snippet sort of suggests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are modifying your own plugin I see no reason your code wouldn't work. The `is_single()` condition is not needed, and will result in the stylesheet being loaded on custom post types and other singles that you don't intend.

However your `wp_enqueue_style` call is incomplete, so unless you have a `wp_register_style` call somewhere else defining the handle and URL of the stylesheet you need to change it to something along these lines:

```
if (is_singular('post')) {
    wp_enqueue_style('savrix-style', plugins_url('savrix-style.css', __FILE__);
}
```

However, I get the impression that you are actually trying to remove a stylesheet included by a thirdparty plugin. It is generally a bad idea to modify a third-party plugin, as your modifications will be lost on the next update... it is very difficult to maintain that sort of modifications in the long run.

Instead make a new plugin and modify whatever you need from there.

What you want to achieve can be accomplished by:

Create a new folder in the `wp-content/plugins` folder, fx. `my_load_reducer`.

Inside that folder create a new file called `my_load_reducer.php`

Paste this in the file:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Load Reducer
Description: Removes unneeded and unwanted stylesheets from other plugins
Version: 0.1
*/

//Use a class to avoid conflicts
class my_load_reducer {
    function __construct() {
        //Hook into wp_enqueue_scripts with a high priority
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'deregister_styles'), 1000 );
    }
    function deregister_styles() {
        //Check that current post is not a single post
        if (!is_singular('post')) {
            //deregister the stylesheet - this removes the twentyfifteen
            //main stylesheet - obviously you need to substitute the handle
            //of the stylesheet you actually want to remove
            wp_deregister_style( 'twentyfifteen-style' );
        }
    }
}

//Instantiate the class
$my_load_reducer = new my_load_reducer();
```

Activate the plugin through the wordpress admin.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove perticular plugin css on selected page.

below code is remove plugin css to other pages and display only on post pages:

```
/*disable loading plugin css to page and load on post page*/

add_action('wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 99999);

function my_deregister_styles() 
{
  if(!is_single())
  {
      wp_dequeue_style('plugin-css-handle');
      wp_deregister_style('plugin-css-handle');  
  }
}
```

where 'plugin-css-handle' is perticular plugin's css handle which you want to remove.